# Wordpress plugin for backup with full back-end

Tags: database, wordpress

I have to work with a WordPress site, which is live now, and I want to install it locally.

My client has its web-hosting through another developer's account => No access to web-hosting files. There is no way to get in contact with that developer.

When I use a WP backup plugin I only deploy the homepage. I can not deploy any other file.

Is any other (legal/moral) way/plugin to download the full back-end so I can install completely that WordPress site?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

BackupBuddy plugin is good for backup and restore. With the help of this plugin you can take backup of full site and database also.

Answer (score 0):

Just to inform others that may have the same question.

I have tried with this plugin (BackupBuddy) and others. You can download a database which will only perform the home page, but it has no access to others DB files, so it shows error 500.

My only choice was to get the host server account and login for downloading the complete database. It makes sense for security reasons.